# Get service status when using `google.maps.Autocomplete`

Tags: google-places-api

I'm using Google places autocomplete:

```
var input = document.getElementById('addressInput');
var options = {};
var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);
```

I'm trying to find a way to hook into `Autocomplete` widget so that i can catch service status to know if there has been error (e.g. request limit reached), but couldn't find a solution so far.

I know I can use `google.maps.places.AutocompleteService()` to make *another* request to Google API and that one *will* have `STATUS` property in response. I'm wondering if there is a way to get status of a request in `google.maps.places.Autocomplete` itself? Help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

There is no way, but you should not need this.

The [Autocomplete class](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Autocomplete) will trigger the `place_changed` event when the user either selects a suggestion or presses Enter. There is no other events that let you know of Autocomplete failing to get suggestions.

However, you should not need this. So long as you use an API key from an API project that has the Places API enabled, you should be fine. Sure, things can go south in many ways and break Autocomplete requests for some users, but unless this is really really important to your application, building your own widget about the [AutocompleteService](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#AutocompleteService) is probably overkill.